# Spivak ed.1 Chapter 22 problem 1 (v)

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

The problem asks to determine whether the following series is convergent of not:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}}
$$
The solution states that it is convergent because for very big n values,
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}} \lt \frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{n^2}}
$$
But I don't get why $\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{n^2}}$ is convergent, I have solved this way:
$$ n^2-1 \lt n^3 \ \ \forall n\gt 2$$
$$ \sqrt[3]{n^2-1} \lt n$$
$$ \frac{1}{n} \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}}$$
And since $ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}}$ should be too.
Could you help me out?

Comment: I would just double check that you copied down the problem correctly.

Comment: I believe that you are correct and the series diverges. The ```SumConvergence``` test in 'Mathematica' also confirms that the series diverges. Perhaps this is a typo in the book or you're reading the question wrong.

Comment: At least in the 4th edition, the answer to this says "diverges".

Comment: I copied the problem correctly, if in more modern editions it says that "diverges", I will let it be. Thank you very much